# How to populate AlertDialog from Arraylist?

Tags: java, android

How to populate AlertDialog from Arraylist.
My Arraylist something like this :

```
{ Brand=Weber,
  Category=Urethane,
  Code=Wpu-01,
  Description=Black,
  Quantity=5;
  Brand=Weber,
  Category=Urethane,
  Code=Wpu-02,
  Description=White,
  Quantity=10}
```

And I want to show that in alertdialog is something like this

Product Details

```
Weber Urethane Wpu-01 Black 5
Weber Urethane Wpu-02 White 10
```

then a button ("CLOSE")

Please help me . Thanks in advance.

This the code

```
public void updateJSONdata() {

    orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(PRODUCTLIST_URL);


    try {


        order = json.getJSONArray(GET_PRODUCT);

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = order.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString(GET_ID);

            String brand = c.getString(GET_BRAND);

            String category = c.getString(GET_CATEGORY);

            String description = c.getString(GET_DESCRIPTION);

            String code = c.getString(GET_CODE);

            String quantity = c.getString(GET_QUANTITY);

            String unit = c.getString(GET_UNIT);

            String unitprice = c.getString(GET_UNITPRICE);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(GET_ID,id);

            map.put(GET_BRAND, brand);

            map.put(GET_CATEGORY, category);

            map.put(GET_DESCRIPTION, description);

            map.put(GET_CODE, code);

            map.put(GET_QUANTITY, quantity);

            map.put(GET_UNIT, unit);

            map.put(GET_UNITPRICE, unitprice);


            orderlist.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: I already used for loop but i can't get any data

Comment: int i;
        for(i=0;i < orderlist.toString().length();i++){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+orderlist.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

Comment: @Mauker  orderlist is the Arraylist i used

Comment: What is the type of the ArrayList? Please show the complete code.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib check the code above

Comment: Wait, are you using an `ArrayList` or a `HashMap`?

Comment: Do you want to show all products in one dialog? or details of a single product at a time in one dialog? Please clarify.

Comment: orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib I want to show all the products in alertdailog

Comment: On a single `AlertDialog`?

Comment: @Mauker Yes if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through your `ArrayList` with `HashMap` and show the data on an `AlertDialog`, try something like:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (HashMap map : list) {
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(((Map.Entry) it.next()).getValue()).append(" ");
    }
    sb.append("\n"); // Use this if you want a line break.
}

String msg = sb.toString();

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Product details")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage(msg)
        .setPositiveButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Do something.
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
```

This will show all the information in one `AlertDialog`.

If you really want to show them all in one single line, remove this line of code:

```
sb.append("\n"); // Use this if you want a line break.
```

Comment: what if I want to show something like this
Weber Urethane Wpu-01 Black 5
Weber Urethane Wpu-02 White 10

Comment: You mean, without the line break?

Comment: Yes Please check the Products details above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87050/discussion-between-mauker-and-paul).

Comment: I edited my post above about products details , How i can show something like the above product details please check

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (HashMap<String,String> product:orderList){
        for (Map.Entry entry:product.entrySet()){
            sb.append(entry.getValue()).append(" ");
        }
    }
String msg = sb.toString();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Product details")
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
```

Comment: Shaoib Thanks for the effort :D. I'm Glad you help me